# How to test option select using React Testing Library in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, react-testing-library

I'm trying to create a test simulating a user selecting a value from a drop down list but I keep getting the error that the error "Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'."

```
fireEvent.change(screen.getByLabelText('Select Color'), { target: { value: 'blue' } })
expect(screen.getByTestId("no-color-selected").selected).toBe(false);
expect(screen.getByTestId("blue-selected").selected).toBe(true);
```

I'm not using a typescript file, so don't know why I'm getting a ts error

I also tried casting it to the proper type but I get the error that I can only do this in Typescript, not JS

```
    expect((screen.getByText('Color Selected: Blue') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(true);
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this or another way to test option select in javascript with react testing lib? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the error surfacing, in your IDE?

Comment: Could you provide the code for the component you're testing?